# Need inexpensive router that supports DHCP reservation

Tags: router

I need to find an inexpensive router that supports DHCP reservation via MAC address.

This is for a production test system for some custom hardware devices that we manufacture. The devices support DHCP and start out with a fixed MAC address. I want to have the router assign a fixed IP address as soon as the device boots up so my test software can ping it to verify that the ethernet port is working. Then, I will disconnect that device and connect another.

So the router needs to support DHCP reservation and be able to sense when the client hardware has been disconnected and a new one reconnected.

And like

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good performance out of the Archer series: [Archer A7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079JD7F7G)
They are cheap, last forever, and they can do DHCP reservations.

For my test systems, I run [Open DHCP](http://dhcpserver.sourceforge.net/) on my computer, assign it to run on a specific IP address and give that IP address to the port I have connected to the equipment. Then I put reserved addresses in the config file if I want them.

Answer (score 0):

The client needs to *ask* for DHCP.
Sophos UTM can do all you ask & is free for 50 seats. All you need is a spare computer, or you can run it in a VM.

They don't make it easy to find, but see this discussion for links & method - https://community.sophos.com/free-tools/f/discussions/130237/looking-for-the-download-iso-for-sophos-utm-home-edition

You need to generate the licence in order to run it. It expires every 3 years, but they send an email to renew it… so use real contact details.